# "charge" or "require"

Tags: word-choice

> Prices are $25 for general admission and $20 for senior citizens and
>   students with a valid ID. Children under 12 will **charge/be charged/require/be required**
>   half price.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 5):

Only "be charged" makes sense here.

"Charge" would imply that the children are charging (somebody something).

Both "require to pay" and "be required to pay" would make sense, but not "require/be required" the price.

Comment: Yes, especially when the price is **less**. (In a different context, though, you could use _be required_, such as: _Non-members will be required to pay a surcharge._)